# Jhipster with JWT authentication integration with okta

Tags: jwt, jhipster, okta, okta-api, jhipster-registry

I have created an application with JWT authentication. I want to integrate with OKTA. Just to gain knowledge I have created a sample application with oauth authentication and was able to successfully integrate with okta.

Now I would like to integrate the already application with JWT authentication with OKTA. Please suggest me how to integrate with okta

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot integrate a JHipster app that uses JWT authentication with Okta. You have to use OAuth / OIDC as your authentication mechanism. One thing you could try is:

1. Make sure your JWT app is checked into source control (for example, a local Git repo).
2. Run `rm -rf` in your JWT app to delete all the files (this will delete everything, but keep your `.yo-rc.json` file and `.jhipster` directory).
3. Modify `.yo-rc.json` to change `authenticationType` to `oauth2`.
4. Run `jhipster --with-entities` to re-create your application with OAuth 2.0 for login.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I made some customisation in authentication. Will they persist or again I have to implement?

Comment: If you made any customizations, you'll need to re-implement them. If you used Git to save your project (and you deleted all its files), you should be able to "diff" everything after creating the new project and restore your changes. However, it's unlikely that JWT auth and OIDC auth share the same classes.